# Custom mouse cursor with CSS in GWT

Tags: css, gwt, libgdx

I'm using libgdx to deploy a GWT app. I'm guessing that the issue has more to do with GWT rather than libgdx since I'm working directly with GWT code and CSS for this.

I want to set the mouse cursor based on an image using CSS, but I can only get it to work with the predefined cursors.

I change the cursor from the code like this:

```
RootPanel.get().setStyleName("mycursor");
```

I've also tried with addStyleName("mycursor") which gives the same result.

Below are some CSS examples of what's working and not working. Note that the problem does not appear to be with the URL path of the image file, since I can use the same path for setting the background.

```
/* Does not work */
.mycursor *, .mycursor .absolutelyPositioned  {
    cursor: url("cursor.png"); 
}

/* Works */
.mycursor *, .mycursor .absolutelyPositioned  {
    cursor: move; 
}


/* The image file is found and working! */
body {
    background-image:url("cursor.png"); /* <-- Works*/
    cursor: url("cursor.png"); /* <-- Does not work */
}
```

When testing the CSS outside of GWT it works fine to set the mouse cursor from an image like this, so I really can't find a reason why this shouldn't work.

Am I missing something, or does GWT (or possibly libgdx) just not like using images for cursors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you link to your cursor image properly. Once you do that, `setStyleName("myCursor");` should work.

I just tried this Grand Theft Auto cursor I found on some blog, and it worked:

```
.myCursor {
    cursor: url(http://i696.photobucket.com/albums/vv323/RoamPT/mouse.png), auto;
}
```

[Here's a CodePen link so you can play around with it.](http://cdpn.io/uCwfB)

See [this link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/) and [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url) for more help.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Your CSS code above works when testing outside of GWT, but the same thing in GWT/libgdx doesn't. The link doesn't seem to be the problem, but have no clue what it can be. I'm so confused...

Comment: I just noticed that Chrome's Developer Tools is claiming the cursor line to be an "Invalid property value." The exact same line is valid on a separate test page. How is this possible?

Comment: It's working now! I had removed the "auto" part of your code which I didn't realize was mandatory, although I could have sworn I tested it in GWT with this part included as well at first. I must have made a typo or something. Though it's weird that it does work outside of GWT without that fallback cursor included. Thanks again!